# Native date parsing library in python

Tags: python, nlp

Do we have any good native python library which is as good as of sutime or duckling. Though there is a wrapper for sutime in python, but it consumes lot of memory. parsedatetime in python isn't as good as these, it cannot handle range.

Comment: Arrow? (https://github.com/crsmithdev/arrow/). Depends on your needs.

Comment: Also, there's https://github.com/wanasit/chrono-python, which might fit better, but isn't maintained really.

Comment: Thanks, let me evaluate these and get back.

Comment: arrow isn't for nlp. chrono-python, though works for very basic cases, but cannot parse anything complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one https://github.com/scrapinghub/dateparser.

`dateparser` -- python parser for human readable dates. It provides modules to easily parse localized dates in almost any string formats commonly found on web pages.